# Why do aircraft take this strange route into JFK?

Tags: instrument-procedures, flight-path, kjfk

Looking at FlightRadar24, I see there is a long line of aircraft heading into JFK, but that they seem to all be starting to head straight at it from over Pennsylvania (as can be seen in the image below, and at https://flightaware.com/live/flight/JBU1042/history/20170621/2301Z/KSAV/KJFK.[image: Example of route]
It's not just JBU1042, though (which looks like it's circling too?). A bunch of aircraft seem to be doing this. And not just ones coming from the western U.S. Many are coming from the south too.[image: FlightRadar24 screenshot]
It doesn't appear that way when I plug the route that FlightAware displays into something like SkyVector.

Comment: What in particular seems strange about this route? What were you expecting to see? We're you expecting a more direct routing?

Comment: @JonathanWalters just that it doesn't seem to follow any arrival procedures I could find, and that it seems a little weird to me that they are being sent over mid-Pennsylvania before being turned and heading straight for the airport. I guess I've just never seen them that far out before, but mainly that it doesn't seem to match up with the routing on FlightAware as well as SkyVector. It also seems interesting that despite the route shown in FA, the blue dotted line does seem to indicate that's where they planned to go, yet it seemingly isn't in the route displayed by FA.

Comment: Well, without comparing it to the charted procedure, that flight path in your first picture looks to me at first glance to be the Lendy Six arrival into JFK. You might look that up and compare the charted arrival route. I would guess that's what they are flying. It starts over the Wilkes-Barre VOR.

Comment: Yep defiantly looks like LENDY6

Comment: I feel that a lot of these questions would be obvious if FlightRadar and alike would overlay NEXRAD on the maps...

Comment: @RonBeyer what do you mean by "displaying NEXRAD on the maps"?

Comment: @lightbord [Weather Radar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NEXRAD)

Comment: @RonBeyer FlightAware has some sort of WX radar on it. Not sure of its data source. I agree it would be nice to have it on FR24 as well.

Comment: @RonBeyer Is that not that what we are seeing in the first image, from FlightAware, NEXRAD or similar?

Comment: Possibly it has something to do with that line of storms blocking the more direct routes into JFK from the south?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Stormy change of arrival plans

Originally, the flight was planned to use the CAMRN4 STAR coming in from SIE VOR south-southwest of KJFK.  However, there is a strong band of storms just south of that VOR on the FlightAware map, blocking that route.  So, the flight got a reroute to pick up the LENDY6 STAR instead, getting vectored northwesterly to around FQM (Williamsport) VOR first and then back onto the course to pick up the STAR in order to provide sufficient space to descend to FL230 by JENNO.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I'm really trying to learn how to understand reroutings and stuff, so may I ask how you were able to determine this? I get that you can tell its LENDY6, but how did you know it was FQM that they got redirected to? And as near as I can tell it looks like they exited the J121 at WEAVR and then direct FQM. But they did do that little loop thing down over North Carolina. No idea what that was. Would my analysis be anywhere near correct or are there other things happening I may not know about?

Comment: I actually just found a thing on flight aware to show enroute charts. My analysis wasn't correct. Except for the little half loop thing in North Carolina, I think I can pretty much figure out their routing. They exited the J121 a little past BARTL. From there they did that loop type thing, possibly direct DIW. Over DIW, they headed straight for J109. Once over and lined up with J109 (008 from ILM), they went direct VALLO, joining J220 for a second. At OGESY, they split onto J227, then at BABEE, they tuned and headed straight for LVZ, where they followed LENDY6. Only unsure about thing over NC.

Comment: @lightbord The NC loop may have simply been a holding pattern further out to allow easier spacing since flights were being rerouted due to weather.